# Retrieve parameters using .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, parameters, get

**I have a jsp file: validate.jsp-**

```
var rollNo=document.forms["result_form"]["studentRollno"].value;
var name=document.forms["result_form"]["studentName"].value;

$("#student_result").load("result.jsp?rollNo="+rollNo+"&name="+name);
```

As you can see, I am passing two data rollNo and name to result.jsp

**Now in result.jsp:**

```
String rollNo=request.getParameter("rollNo");
String name=request.getParameter("name");       

out.print("Your roll number is: "+rollNo+"<br>");
out.print("Your name is: "+name);
```

Everything is fine. When I give rollNo=5 and name=something(in the textboxes in validate.jsp), result.jsp loads displaying the message as I intended. The only problem is, it works only as long as I don't give spaces in the textboxes!! For ex: If I enter name="Stalin", it works but for name="Stalin " and "Stalin Subramanaim", it doesn't work. result.jsp page doesn't load! Please help..!!

Comment: Please add code formatting for clarity.

Comment: I would guess you have to encode your params before sending them as the spaces when they are passed and encoded turn to %20% I beleive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are building the parameters by hand which can result in an improperly formatted query string. You should use the jQuery helper [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to solve this:

```
el.load( "result.jsp?" + $.param( { rollNo: rollNo, name: name } ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not working because you cant have whitespaces in a url. You need to transform the whitespaces into special characters (javascript function `escape(url)` will be fine)